# How can I store in a vector the result of a function in R

Tags: r

How can I store in a vector the result of a function in R. 
For instance. 
The function `measures(out, 0.999)` give me the following result:

```
       p quantile    sfall
 [1,] 0.99 2.826164 3.758789.
```

I want to store the value of `2.8261`, How can I do it?

Comment: looks like a matrix. perhaps `v1 <- measures(out, 0.999)[,2]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had no idea how to do it, I was getting crazy, so I really thanfully your help,

Answer (score 2):

@akrun is right, but I'd rather use a call to the name of the column.
Moreover, if you want the result to be stored only up to the 4th decimal, you can wrap the result into a `round` function, like the following code does:

```
stored_quantile <- round(measures(out, 0.999)$quantile,4)
```

**EDIT**: the reason for preferring my solution is that if the function `measures` would produce a different output order between the columns you would always be sure to get the value you are interested in (i.e.: `quantile`)